# Are parallel Docker contexts possible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can we pull in docker services, and build containers, using projects and paths that are *not* a child of the current directory?

Example:

```
/ application-a     <- needs api01 & api03 (not api02)
  - .git
  - docker-compose.yml
  / src
/ application-a     <- needs api01 & api02 (not api03)
  - .git
  - docker-compose.yml
  / src

/ api01
  - .git
  - Dockerfile
  / src
/ api02
  - .git
  - Dockerfile
  / src
/ api03
  - .git
  - Dockerfile
  / src
```

Every path I try causes an error.  Most of the errors are complaining about the context.

Our company is porting approximately 50 webservices from .NET to microservices using Express.  However, not all of our front-end and consuming applications require access to all of the backend services.  We also want to restrict access to only those projects and repos they need access to.

The goal is to let a user checkout the api services they need and then the one primary application they are working on.  The source folders would end up being parallel to each other on the developer's laptop.

I would *love* to do this within the `docker-compose.yml` of the associated application...

```
version: '2'

services:

  api01:
    build:
      context: ..
    container_name: api01
    command:
      bash -c "npm install && nodemon"
    volumes:
      - app01/src:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    ports:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - backend

  api02:
    build:
      context: ..
    container_name: api02
    command:
      bash -c "npm install && nodemon"
    volumes:
      - app02/src:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    ports:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding the directory name to the `context:` and `volumes:` paths will solve this:

```
version: '2'

services:

  api01:
    build:
      context: ../app01
    container_name: api01
    command:
      bash -c "npm install && nodemon"
    volumes:
      - ../app01/src:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    ports:
      - "3000"
networks:
  - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach. I use a metarepository - Basically an outer repository that contains other repositories.

Here are a couple of implementations:
https://github.com/mateodelnorte/meta
http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/

You can have multiple meta-repositories that contain different subsets of the child repos. It's ok if they overlap. Inside of that meta repo would be a perfect place to put your docker-compose files.

Your developer's workflows would be the following:

```
meta git clone git@github.com:yourOrg/project-name.git
cd project-name
docker-compose up
```

Where your docker-compose.yml file would look like this:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  service:
  site:

services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    networks:
      - service

  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - service

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - site

  site:
    build: ./nycnode-site
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
     - ./nycnode-site:/home/app/site
     - /home/app/site/node_modules
    environment:
     - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/nycnode
     - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - site

  meetup-ingestor:
    build: ./nycnode-meetup-ingestor
    volumes:
     - ./nycnode-meetup-ingestor:/home/app/meetup-ingestor
     - /home/app/meetup-ingestor/node_modules
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:5672
     - REDIS.HOST=redis
     - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - service

  user-ingestor:
    build: ./nycnode-user-ingestor
    volumes:
     - ./nycnode-user-ingestor:/home/app/user-ingestor
     - /home/app/user-ingestor/node_modules
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:5672
     - REDIS.HOST=redis
     - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - service

  youtube-ingestor:
    build: ./nycnode-youtube-ingestor
    volumes:
     - ./nycnode-youtube-ingestor:/home/app/youtube-ingestor
     - /home/app/youtube-ingestor/node_modules
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:5672
     - REDIS.HOST=redis
     - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - service

  denormalizer:
    build: ./nycnode-denormalizer
    volumes:
     - ./nycnode-denormalizer:/home/app/denormalizer
     - /home/app/denormalizer/node_modules
    ports:
     - "3001:3001"
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:5672
     - REDIS.HOST=redis
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/nycnode
     - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - service
      - site
```

Also, there is nothing stopping you from having multiple docker-compose.yml files.

You may specify which one you'd like to use with the `-f` flag

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-subset-A.yml up
```